# How do you get the original filename of a sprite/texture in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I create a sprite and assign an image file to it.

```
var logoImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image1.png")
```

Then in some circumstances, I change the image.

```
logoImage.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "image2.png")
```

In another part of the app I want to check which image is currently being displayed. But I don't know how to get the filename.

Using:

```
print(logoImage.texture?.description)
```

Returns:

```
"<SKTexture> 'image2.png' (500 x 500)"
```

Which obviously contains the filename, but how do I get the filename on it's own?

Comment: you can use logoImage.name = "image1"  property

Comment: You are doing it wrong. If you want to check which image is displayed, save the name separately. Don't try to read information from your UI about your data model.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest your to avoid exposing the internal logic of your objects.

And definitely you should **NOT** build your game logic on the texture currently used. The presentation should be a mere representation of the actual data.

So you should create your own class that wraps logic and data, like this.

```
class Logo: SKSpriteNode {

    enum Type: String {
        case A = "Image1", B = "Image2"
        var imageName: String {
            return self.rawValue
        }
    }

    private var type: Type {
        didSet {
            self.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: type.imageName)
        }
    }

    init(type: Type) {
        self.type = type
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: type.imageName)
        super.init(texture: texture, color: .clearColor(), size: texture.size())
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

### Usage

Now you can easily create a Logo

```
let logo = Logo(type: .A)
```

You can change the texture for that sprite

```
logo.type = .B
```

And you can check what texture is currently using

```
switch logo.type {
case .A: print("It's using Image1")
case .B: print("it's using Image2")
}
```

> Last thing. I replaced `Image1.png` and `Image2.png` with `Image1` and `Image2`. If you are using Asset Catalog (and you should) then you don't need to specify the file extension.

Comment: great advice @appzYourLife!!

Comment: I have a problem in this part (Swift 3.0)
private var type: Type {
        didSet {
            self.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: type.imageName)
        }
    }

I get an error message: "type is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level"
When I try to change the texture for that sprite
logo.type = .B

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
if logoImage.texture?.descriptio.containsString("image1.png") {
   // your code for image1 here
} else {
   // your code for image2 here
}
```

You'll have use:

```
import Foundation
```

in your code for `containsString`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that there is a more elegant method but it works:

```
if let rangeOfIndex = texture.description.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "'"), options: .BackwardsSearch) {
   let filename = texture.description.substringToIndex(rangeOfIndex.endIndex)
   if let r = filename.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "'"), options: .LiteralSearch) {
      print(filename.substringFromIndex(r.startIndex).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("'", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil))
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this :

```
func getTextureName(textureTmp: String) -> String {
    var texture:String = ""
    var startInput = false
    for char in textureTmp {
        if startInput {
            if char != "'" {
                texture += String(char)
            } else {
                return texture
            }
        }
        if char == "'" {
            startInput = true
        }
    }
    return texture
}
```

Its not beautiful but it works