# finding the texture name in swift

Tags: xcode, swift3, sprite-kit

I'm trying to develop a simple game using swift 3's sprite Kit. I would like to run different animations based on the current texture, like

```
if self.texture.name == "Jump2" {
    self.run(Jump_Ouch6, withKey: "Jump_Ouch6")
} else if self.texture.name == "Jump3" {
    self.run(Jump_Ouch7, withKey: "Jump_Ouch7")
}
```

The problem is I cannot find a means of returning the name of the current texture.

Some things I've tried are:

Using

```
print(texture?.description.contains("Jump2"))
```

prints a "Optional(Bool)"

which I took to mean I was on the right track.... but using

```
    if (texture?.description.contains("Jump2"))! {
        print ("Hi")
    } else {
        print ("Bye")
    }
```

gives a EXC_BREAKPOINT

I've looked at some other posts on here from a google search like

[How do you get the original filename of a sprite/texture in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296496/how-do-you-get-the-original-filename-of-a-sprite-texture-in-swift)

The class returns an entire SKSpriteNode though, which does not really fit what I need. Still I spent 3 + hours thinking maybe I could enum the texture then pass is to the function that I use to create the animations. But still I only pass the texture name and am left in the same place.

Any help??

Comment: You are force unwrapping the whole statement. Firstly, try to investigate why your `texture` is `nil`.

Comment: Hi thanks. Looking to the print statement I do get a nil at the start of the terminal output. If I use a conditional to check for a nil then I can get a result back. Yes texture is "xxx", texture is Not "xxx"

Comment: I was more looking for a way to directly access the name of a texture either directly through Xcode i.e texture.name, or through another means such as passing a struct to the SKAction, but I can't see that working. There must be a way though right? I mean otherwise this is a lot of switch and if statements

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are better ways but this seems to work well

```
    func textureName() -> String {
        var textDesc = String()
        if texture?.description != nil {
            textDesc = (texture?.description)!
            let indexStart = textDesc.index(textDesc.startIndex, offsetBy: 13)
            let indexEnd = textDesc.index(textDesc.endIndex, offsetBy: -13)
            let textName = textDesc[indexStart..<indexEnd]
            return textName
        } else {
            return "nil"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a different approach all together,  that is a lot of CPU cycles you are burning up just to find a name.  Instead, I would recommend checking the `hashValue` It is an integer comparison which make things a lot faster.  You could even setup a dictionary to help you distinguish different values a lot easier, like:

```
names = ["Jump1":jump1.hashValue,"Jump2":jump.hashValue]
if texture.hashValue = names["Jump1"]
```

Now keep in mind it is possible for the hashValue to conflict with other textures, so I would recommend doing a test to make sure all of your textures have unique hashValues.

If you find that they are colliding,  then you may need to find something else like using the hashValue of the description or extending SKTexture to give it functionality to derive a unique identifier.